# Creating IEEE References in Ph.D Thesis

Tags: lyx, templates, thesis, ieee-style

How to create IEEE standards  references/citations, figures, tables in writing Ph.D Computer Science & Engineering thesis . Lyx tutorials/guide is helpful some extent, is there any templates like Latex so that we can edit and use it for our thesis in IEEE standard.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) Please edit your posting to indicate *which* template you're thinking of -- there are a lot of them out there. It looks like you're using BibTeX to format the references; to edit the file that contains the raw references (the file usually has extension `.bib`), no special editor is required.

Comment: There is no thesis standard of IEEE. Do you mean the look of the thesis? Fonts? Margins? What do you mean by IEEE references in the title? Is it the bibliography or the template you ask for? Please add more specific details to narrow down the focus.